# Specific area from SurfaceView

Tags: android

I need a small help. I have added Google Vision API to detect text from image and for that, the image comes from camera, so it is dynamic. The camera is laid on SurfaceView and text, that is found on the surfaceView is captured. I want the feature where SurfaceView captures the whole image, but the text is taken only from specific area defined by me. To say in short, "add limit in the camera (Like a rectangle) so that the data/text that the image processes is from that rectangle only"

```
mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, textRecognizer)
        .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
        .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
        .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
        .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
        .build();

mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(RechargeActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RechargeActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        RequestCameraPermissionID);
                return;
            }
            mCameraSource.start(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCameraSource.stop();
    }
});
```